# Document non-global lightning components

Tags: lightning, documentation

Adding a `.auradoc` on a global Lightning component adds documentation to the /auradocs/reference.app page. Fine. Nice.

Is there a way to generate documentation for my team internally for the non-global components?

Comment: auradoc works on all types of bundles, not just those marked as global.

Comment: The code I'm looking at lives in a managed package. Perhaps that changes the equation?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to access non-global components outside of the package's code, so I presume you can't see the documentation, either. The documentation would be visible only in the packaging org.